# Mustache with JSON do not execute the function

Tags: jquery, json, mustache, couchapp

I'm trying to create couchapp with jquery, mustache and sammy. There will be several pages and I will generate them like this:

```
$(function () {
var $db = $.couch.db('test');
var app = $.sammy(function () {
    this.get('#/', function () {
        render('json/index.json', 'mustache/index.ms');
    });
    this.get('#/login', function () {
        render('json/login.json', 'mustache/login.ms');
    });
    this.get('#/register', function () {
        render('json/register.json', 'mustache/register.ms');
    });
    this.put('#/post/register', register);
    this.put('#/post/login', login);
});
app.run('#/')});
```

and then:

```
function render(xjson, xms) {
$.getJSON(xjson, function (data) {
    $.get(xms, function (template) {
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').append(html);
    });
});}
```

.js are JSON files where I store the data. .ms files are mustache templates. Thing is that when I try to put a function to JSON like it's described here:
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

```
 var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function() {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
}

var template = "{{title}} spends {{calc}}";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, view);
```

The function will not execute. So, what I'm doing wrong? Is it a good idea to store data and functions in JSON and what alternatives do I have?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your lambda isnt declared correctly.. your json should return an anonymous function which mustache will execute.

here is how you should be doing it.

```
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function() {
     return function(text) {return (2 + 4)}
  }
}

var template = "{{title}} spends {{#calc}} {{/calc}}";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, view);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/hqQRd/)